# Strange behaviour in Chromium browsers with scrollable overflow

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have some custom drop-down menues that are acting strange.

https://bohuslansmuseum.iplace.se/kunskapsbanken/

The drop-downs looks alright, til you start scrolling down. Then you'll notice that the
background starts flickering and behaving strangely. Also, when you hover over them they start flickering.

The problem is only visible on chromium based browsers, and I've tested it on both Mac and Windows. I've tested it in safari and firefox, and there they behave correctly.

If anyone has any idea to how I should tackle this would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty lost to what to do, I've tried the basics with playing around with `display` `background` but I'm currently clueless.

Edit:
The problem remains even with `overflow:auto`. Have changed the title to match.

Comment: Are you sure that this behaviour is caused by overflow scroll? I.e. if you have `overflow:auto;` the issue goes away?

Comment: Good point. Can confirm now that the problem remains with `overflow:auto`.